# How to get the actual name of file on server?

Tags: java

I tried to get the name of file from an URL like:

**http://www.example.com/to/the/path/File.txt**

in java by:

```
public String getFileName(URL url) {    
   String filename = url.getFile();    
   return filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('/')+1); 
}
```

But how to get the actual file name of a file from:

**https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0BwScoO2FIDnQQlF2cHVLbHBjQzg**
*(Its a public shared file on my Google drive.)*

I often see that when I put such kind of urls in my web browser's address bar , It is able recognize the name of the file and save it with its actual file name. Is it possible in java?

Thanks!

Comment: Send an HTTP request and read the `Content-Disposition` header, if any.

Comment: You may have to use the Google Drive API to accomplish this if you are going to interact with a Google drive- https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/drive/v2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, simply put, you'll need to investigate what exactly goes under the hood. Get the [CURL](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html) to see what's going on:

```
curl -D - -o /dev/null -L "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0BwScoO2FIDnQQlF2cHVLbHBjQzg"
```

that will give you something like:

```
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
    Pragma: no-cache
    Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
    Date: Fri, 03 Apr 2015 17:42:47 GMT
    Location: https://doc-0c-8k-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/ha0ro937gcuc7l7deffksulhg5h7mbp1/m2vr72uv54vrhd59tvsm5ellda89n0s6/1428076800000/17869486772410674836/*/0BwScoO2FIDnQQlF2cHVLbHBjQzg?e=download
    Set-Cookie: NID=67=fxFK6wjqCslAMuLajOnHKWYlkVAJDG6gMzoQnsDZI2wkd5QlP7meP8tDQJEQk9veY0UUOtSZWAjM_JbHAOMcJavkHU2B6-VDUo3jRpBQSm0moWVmN689L-I1vKgGJoVK;Domain=.google.com;Path=/;Expires=Sat, 03-Oct-2015 17:42:47 GMT;HttpOnly
    P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info."
    X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
    X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
    X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
    Server: GSE
    Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic,p=0.5
    Accept-Ranges: none
    Vary: Accept-Encoding
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked

    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
    Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: false
    Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, Accept-Language, Authorization, Cache-Control, Content-Disposition, Content-Encoding, Content-Language, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Range, Content-Type, Date, GData-Version, Host, If-Match, If-Modified-Since, If-None-Match, If-Unmodified-Since, Origin, OriginToken, Pragma, Range, Slug, Transfer-Encoding, X-ClientDetails, X-GData-Client, X-GData-Key, X-Goog-AuthUser, X-Goog-PageId, X-Goog-Encode-Response-If-Executable, X-Goog-Correlation-Id, X-Goog-Request-Info, X-Goog-Experiments, x-goog-iam-role, x-goog-iam-authorization-token, X-Goog-Spatula, X-Goog-Upload-Command, X-Goog-Upload-Content-Disposition, X-Goog-Upload-Content-Length, X-Goog-Upload-Content-Type, X-Goog-Upload-File-Name, X-Goog-Upload-Offset, X-Goog-Upload-Protocol, X-Goog-Visitor-Id, X-HTTP-Method-Override, X-JavaScript-User-Agent, X-Pan-Versionid, X-Origin, X-Referer, X-Upload-Content-Length, X-Upload-Content-Type, X-Use-HTTP-Status-Code-Override, X-YouTube-VVT, X-YouTube-Page-CL, X-YouTube-Page-Timestamp
    Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,OPTIONS
    Content-Type: application/zip
    Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="All.zip";filename*=UTF-8''All.zip
    Date: Fri, 03 Apr 2015 17:42:47 GMT
    Expires: Fri, 03 Apr 2015 17:42:47 GMT
    Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
    X-Goog-Hash: crc32c=yKvC2Q==
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    Server: UploadServer ("Built on Mar 27 2015 13:04:19 (1427486659)")
    Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic,p=0.5
```

Here, you can see that:

- there is the redirect to another URL https://doc-0c-8k-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/ha0ro937gcuc7l7deffksulhg5h7mbp1/m2vr72uv54vrhd59tvsm5ellda89n0s6/1428076800000/17869486772410674836/*/0BwScoO2FIDnQQlF2cHVLbHBjQzg?e=download
- the document at that URL is returned as an attachment, so you'll need to examine the value of the header **Content-Disposition:**, that will give you the name **filename="All.zip"**.

So now you'd like to automate this, perhaps - and [this link](http://www.coderanch.com/t/273122/java/java/Downloading-Files-Commons-HttpClient) will help you out.

Happy learning!

Answer (score 0):

You can create Object of File class and call getName() method to get absolute name of file.

```
    File file = new File("http://www.example.com/to/the/path/File.txt");
    System.out.println(file.getName());
```

You can not get file name if you do not have absolute path of the file and google docs path is not absolute file path.

Comment: Thank you sir, But the **web browsers** and **download managers** are able to get the actual file name when we put that kind of 'URL(s)' in the address bar.  You can check this by clicking on the URL(given by me).  It will not save the file as 'uc' but as 'All.zip' .